# 3D graphics in Delphi/Native TForm GUIs

Tags: delphi, opengl, 3d, directx

What is the easiest way to do accelerated 3D graphics inside a TForm in Delphi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a library such as Asphyre (http://afterwarp.net/), which supports both DirectX and OpenGL.

Answer (score 4):

You can use GLScene (http://www.glscene.org) for that. GLScene is component-based, has a Viewer-Component (similar than a TPanel) which shows the rendered scene on a form.

I recommend to use the CVS Version, because the latest snapshot is quite old. GLScene works also with Freepascal / Lazarus on several platforms and has many demos.

Answer (score 1):

In Delphi 2010, if running on Windows 7, you can use Direct2D natively.

Comment: Now that's really interesting - I guess we'll make an upgrade soon :-)

Answer (score 0):

Embarcadero Developer Network gives an example (http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26401) to insert code in a traditional TForm. It is easy to convert a console application (with WinMain) to a usual Delphi form. The OpenGL drawing is performed in the Paint method of the TForm. Very few instructions are needed to get results, compared to the console template not very convenient for beginners.